# How to communicate between background.js and content.js using manifest v3 in building a Google Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser-extension

I'm trying to send a request from background.js to content.js but it gives me an error saying:

`Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.`

I have even tried to use the google chrome example in their documentation and that did not work. Probably I'm missing something somewhere. I would appreciate your support!

Manifest.js

```json
{
    "name": "test",
    "description": "test",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "author": "test",

    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["scripts/content.js"]
      }
    ],

    "action": {
    },

    "background": {
      "service_worker": "scripts/background.js"
    },

    "permissions": [
      "tabs"
    ],

    "host_permissions": [
      "*://*/*"
    ]
}
```

content.js

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( (request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  console.log(request);
})
```

```js
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(
  (tab) => {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {response: "Hello World"})
  }
)
```

The tree of folder is:

```
manifest.json
scripts/background.js
scripts/content.js
```

Comment: Have you refreshed the extension ? Have you refreshed the tab that is active when you press the extension's icon ?

Comment: @Titus , Yes I did

Answer (score 1):

I found the mistake that I've been doing. The example in the documentation was fine but I was printing `console.log(request)` and checking the console of the extension itself and I should've checked the console of the current page since it was in `content.js` and not in the `background.js`